# Python sleep() function not working in order

Tags: python, pyqt5, sleep

```
self.statusBar().showMessage("Product added to database")
self.lineEdit_20.setText("")
self.lineEdit_21.setText("")
self.lineEdit_22.setText("")
time.sleep(3)
self.statusBar().showMessage("")
```

This is a part of my code in a PyQt5 project. Here is what i expect to happen:

1. Status bar shows "Product added to database". Line edits show "".
2. 3 seconds pass.
3. Status bar shows "".

Yet here is what happens:

1. Status bar shows "Product added to database".
2. 3 seconds pass.
3. Line edits show "". Status bar shows "".

sleep() function doesnt seem to work in correct order. What is the issue here?

Comment: Not sure if it is related to your issue, but you should probably not use `time.sleep()` in a GUI program. If called on the main thread, it will render the GUI unresponsive because it blocks the event loop.

Comment: `time.sleep()` is unpredictable in a GUI. Why not use QTimer? `QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: self.statusBar().showMessage(""))`

Comment: Thanks a lot alec. It solves my problem.